# opencart - want to add product pricing details to order/invoice

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am developing a jewellery shopping cart. I want to show product description like metal price, making charges, gem charges to the order/invoice. On the product display page I have shown all this information in product attributes/specification.
But I am not sure how to add product specification to the order/invoide?

Please guide me..

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You should store this in a SQL. 
If you need guidance, take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp 
 Then, find the specifiek product data to the order, or read it when at "Your orders" through query's.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell that I am customizing Opencart 1.5.6